# Building widgets outside of AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to build a widget, for example a button, in the barrier area of a dialog? By the barrier area I mean the area out of the bounds of an AlertDialog. For example: an AlertDialog is shown in the middle of the screen and a TextButton is in the bottom-right of the screen outside of shown AlertDialog.

Comment: Yeah check the source of `AlertDialog` copy it and implement your own layout.

Comment: could you provide some visual or images? @kforjan

Comment: You could also add an Overlay

Answer (score 2):

You just call from outside and pass the context

```
getDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
            child: AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              content: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: TextButton(
                            child: Text("Close"),
                          )),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ));
}
```

Here is the full source code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_test/screen/shop_card.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "ListView.builder",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeApp(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            getDialog(context);
          },
          child: Center(child: Text("Open Dialog")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

getDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
            child: AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              content: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: TextButton(
                            child: Text("Close"),
                          )),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ));
}
```

output:

[image]